# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting Isn't Working

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am making a spreadsheet in Google Sheets and my conditional formatting works in some cells and not in others. I have gone so far as to delete all of the formattings for the entire workbook and started over. I have been entering the formatting one cell at a time to see if that would solve my problem. There are still cells that the formatting doesn't come up in. I am trying to have a cell turn green if the number in the cell is greater than or equal to a certain number. HELP! I'm going crazy!

Comment: Show us what you did and the data in your sheet working correctly and incorrectly

Comment: Oh, you wrote a lot below the answer. **That should be in your question**

Answer (score 1):

- select a range where Conditional formatting should be applied (**`A1:Z`**)
- then choose **Greater than or equal to**
- and enter your desired number (**`5`**)

  [image: 0]

  ---

your issue is that **P7** is not really 98%. it's rounded up! you can check this with **<kbd>.00</kbd>** button:

[image: 0]

you can fix it also in the early stage with: **`=ROUNDDOWN(SUM(N7)/(N7+O7),2)`**

[image: 0]

Comment: That is how I enter the formatting but there are still cells where it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IeGJiMGSG63lANWi_F1r2pvTXx8IsGdi8RKZcpC3U4E/edit#gid=641995318     some of the cells that are causing me trouble are: P7, BH6, BX3, BX7, CH3, CP4

Comment: How do I share with everyone? I only have the option of entering e-mail addresses.

Comment: okay it's done.

Comment: the 1st sheet and these cells are the problem cells: P7, BH6, BX3, BX7, CH3, CP4

Comment: Will it fix it if I change the formatting to be greater than 97%?

Comment: Yay! It fixed it! Thank you so much! It was driving me crazy!

Comment: @SuzySanders https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers